# React Bootstrap Panel Collapsible not working

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap, panel

I am trying to toggle collapse the panel body when panel heading is clicked. I have react-bootstrap 0.34.2.

When the page is loaded the body is also visible but when the header is clicked ( twice) toggle starts working.

How can I make sure the body is not visible when the page loads and only visible when panel heading is clicked.

```
                <PanelGroup id={'log'} className ={style.panelgroup}>
                    {
                        data.map((exception, index1) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index1}>
                                    <Panel eventKey={index1} key={index1} >
                                        <Panel.Heading>
                                            <Panel.Title toggle>
                                                <div className={style.header}>
                                                    <div className={style.key}>{e.time}</div>
                                                    <div className={style.value}>{exception.stack}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </Panel.Title>
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                        <Panel.Body Collapsible>
                                            <div className={style['logItem-body']}>{exception.stack.map((traceString, index2) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <div key={index2}>{traceString}</div>
                                                );
                                            })}
                                            </div>
                                        </Panel.Body>
                                    </Panel>
                                </div>

                            );
                        })
                    }
                </PanelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this from the react bootstrap docs. It shows `expanded={this.state.open}` in the panel line. They are defining the initial state for `open` at the top where it says `this.state = { open: true }`. All you would have to do is set this to false so that the panel would initially be closed.

It doesn't look like you are using state anywhere in your code. So make sure you are setting the initial state at the top, have the button you click toggle the state, and set the panel property `expanded` to the same state. Here is a [link to the specific bootstrap doc you will neeed.](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/panel/)Good luck!

```js
    this.state = {
      open: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
          Click to toggle
        </Button>
        <br />
        <Panel id="collapsible-panel-example-1" expanded={this.state.open}>
          <Panel.Collapse>
            <Panel.Body>
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
              accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh
              helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente
              ea proident.
            </Panel.Body>
          </Panel.Collapse>
        </Panel>
```

Comment: Same thing is happening here. the body is visible even before clicking the button.

Comment: @user3594118 did you set the initial state as false? `    this.state = {open: false};`

Comment: yes I did that as well